# Confidence Interval of estimator for the exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, deviance, exponential-distribution

> We have an exponential distribution  $$f(x)=\frac{e^\frac{-x}{\theta}}{\theta}$$
>
> We are told that $n=3$ and that the data are given as
>   $x_1=1, x_2=2.5, x_3=5.5$
>
> a.) Determine an approximate 95% confidence interval based on asymptotic normality of $\overline{x}$
>
> b.) Determine an approximate 95% confidence interval based on the asymptotic distribution of the deviance $D(\theta)$. The solution does not have to be exact. Pay attention to the function g, defined as $$g(\theta)= \frac{3}{\theta}+\ln\theta -\ln3-1$$

My questions:

a.) I have to take the sample mean, and then I add up the $z_{ \frac{\alpha}{2} }\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$ thing? With $z_{0.025}=1.96?$ What value do I use for $\sigma$?

b.) What deviance $D(\theta)$ mean? The question added a graph, on the x-axis I see theta from 0 to 14 and on the y-axis I see (a probability?) from 0.0 up to 1.0 Has this something to do with the power function of the test? I should have knowledge about Neyman-Pearson, likelihood ratio tests, power function of a test.

Comment: Regarding the first question, one would think that $n=3$ is too small for an asymptotic distribution to hold. An [exact confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403059/how-do-we-build-a-confidence-interval-for-the-parameter-of-the-exponential-distr) would be better here. But if one has to use the large sample approximation, then the relevant asymptotic distribution of $\overline X$ is given by $\sqrt{n}(\overline X-\theta)\stackrel{a}\sim N(0,\theta^2)$. Then use the pivot $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\overline X-\theta)}{\theta}\stackrel{a}\sim N(0,1)$.